# Using Hazelcast / Redis for DB backed cache requirement

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, redis, hazelcast

I am developing a distributed Java application that needs to check a list of blacklist userids on each request.

If request fails on some eligibility rules, system should add userid ( a parameter of request ) to blacklist.

I am trying to find a proper caching solution for blacklist implementation. My requirements are;

- querying blacklist should be very fast
- blacklist persistence technology should be scalable
- all blacklist data should be persisted on a RDBMS also for fail over / reloading purposes.

They are two possible solutions;

**Option 1**: I can use redis for storing blacklist data. Whenever a request fails on eligibility rules I can add userid to redis cache easly. 
- advantages: extremely fast query, easy to implement
- disadvantages: trusting on redis persistency although it works, it is a cache solution by design not a persistency layer.

**Option 2**: I can use redis for storing blacklist data meanwhile I can maintain db tables on RDBMS for blacklist. Whenever a request fails on eligibility rules I can add userid to redis cache and rdbms table together. 
- advantages: extremely fast query, ability(possibility) to reload redis cache from db 
- disadvantages: there is a consistency issue between redis and db table.

**Option 3**: I can use hazelcast as hibernate L2 cache and when I add any user id to blacklist it is both added to cache and db.

I have questions about option 3

- Does hazelcast L2 cache is suitable for preserving such a list of blacklisted users?
- Does hibernate manages consistency issue between cache and db?
- When application restarted, how L2 cache is reloaded?

and a last question
- Do you have any other suggestion for such a use-case?

Edit:

- There will be 100m records in blacklist and I have a couple smilar blacklist.
- my read performance is important. I need to query existence of a key within blacklist ~100ms

Comment: What would your "query" look like? I would expect a blacklist being mainly pure key-based access (for example based on the username or userid). Can you clarify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ygok,

Still waiting for clarification on the query requirements but I can assume it a lookup by key (since you mention Redis and Redis doesn't have a query language. Hazelcast does have [Distributed Query / Predicate API](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/manual/html-single/index.html#distributed-query)). 
Lookup by key is an extremely fast operation with Hazelcast.

In **option 2** you need to maintain data consistency between your RDBMS and Redis cache. Using Hazelcast [`MapLoader` / `MapStore`](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/manual/html-single/index.html#loading-and-storing-persistent-data) you can implement `write-through`- / `read-through`- cache concepts. All you need to do is put the entry to the cache, and Hazelcast persists it immediately or with configured delay (with batching) to the RDBMS.

In terms of performance, please, feel free to make yourself familiar with recent [Hazelcast / Redis benchmark](https://hazelcast.com/resources/benchmark-redis-vs-hazelcast/).

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar question before, first of all, how much data do you want to store and spend how much memory? how fast query per second do you need? what the data structure like, only userId as a key?

- Hazelcast query not very fast on my testing(you can do it for yourself), but it can store large memory data. Hazelcast using Java
  default serialize, it cost a lot of memory and IO.
- Hazelcast provide hibernate L2 cache, cache data store on
  Hazelcast(only query cache), so restart your application not affect
  the cache.
- Redis provide memory data persistence(DUMP and AOF), maybe a
  bit of data will be lost when server crashed, but it very fast.
- If you want to not lose any data, store on multi MySQL
  server(split data by userId to different server, but you should
  consider the problems when add new server), at the same time, you can
  add local cache (e.g. Ehcache or google CacheBuilder) and set a
  expire time, it can be promote performance.

Comment: Maybe you can chose Redis(Master/Slave with sentinel mode), if you key length is  10 bytes, 100000000 * 10 bytes nearly cost 1GB memory, use dump persistent mode. And must be store on RDBMS for other uses? if only consider data lose, backup the Redis dump file to NAS by scripts.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to maintain consistency between Redis cache and RDBMS using [Redisson](https://redisson.org) framework. It provides `write-through` and `read-through` strategies for Map object using `MapWriter` and `MapLoader` objects which are required to use in your case.

Please read this [documentation section](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/7.-Distributed-collections#712-map-persistence)